# Not able to invoke Selenium Tests on Windows From Linux Box

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have Selenium WebDriver tests running on Windows box and I need to invoke those tests from Linux Box.Test runs well when I run the same from Windows box. I am using SSH to run tests on Linux.When I am trying to do that I am getting following error.

```
INFO: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. 
Firefox console output:
LOG addons.xpi: startup

LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local

LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share

LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous5065365792772883950webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging

LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges

LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database

LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile

Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
LOG addons.xpi-utils: Database closed
LOG addons.xpi: startup
LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
```

Comment: have you specified a new firefox binary location in your code, when you test on linux?

Comment: Tests are running on Windows only....Firefox location has been specified in Windows.